# Plotting quantile regressions lines generated from one dataset and overlaying those lines onto another scatter plot keeping source format

Tags: r, ggplot2, quantile-regression

I have generated a scatter plot and quantile lines using a a taus <- c(.05,.25,.5,.75,.95) and I am happy with the over all outcome, but it seems like my code is repeating a bit. when I create a manual scale I have to repeat the portions of the code to get the legend cleaned up.

First question: How do I select the text in the legend and color a selected variable of my choosing?
I would like to color Clough Island and Steelton Bay DarkBlue...

![enter image description here][1]

It seems I cannot enter images yet or csv of data... I am posting anyways sorry for the lack of data.

Second question: How do I plot the qeom_quantile regression lines from the first Plot (gg_taus) and place them on a new scatter plot.  My current code is creating a new quantile regression but I want the first.

![enter image description here][2]

Code is as follows:

```
    library(tidyverse)
    library(dplyr)
    library(tidyr)
    library(readr)
    library(plyr)
    library(summarytools)
    library(ggplot2)library(quantreg)
```

```
First scatter plot
```

```
gg <- ggplot(ESB_REF, aes(x=WaterDepth_m,y=S_TMI)) + 
      geom_point(aes(shape=Assessment_Area,))+
      theme(panel.border = element_rect(linetype = "solid", fill = NA), panel.grid.major = element_blank(),
        panel.grid.minor = element_blank(), panel.background = element_blank()) + 
      scale_y_continuous(limits = c(0, 1))+
      scale_x_continuous(breaks = seq(from = 0, to = 3, by = 0.5))+
      xlab("Water Depth (meters)") + ylab("Std.Macroinvertebrete Trimetric Index (sTMI)")+
      labs(shape="Assessment Areas")
gg
```

```
Building a plot with selected taus capturing a range of quantiles in steps  
but cant change the legend variable text color
```

```
taus <- c(.05,.25,.5,.75,.95)

gg_taus <- gg + 
  geom_quantile(quantiles = taus, aes(linetype = factor(..quantile..),colour = factor(..quantile..), size = factor(..quantile..) ))

gg_taus <- gg_taus + scale_colour_manual(breaks=c(.05, .25, .5, .75, .95),
                        values=c("red", "red","black", "green", "green"),
                        name="Quantile Factors",
                        labels=c(" 5th  Percentile", "25th Percentile","Median", "75th Percentile", "95th Percentile")) +
                     scale_size_manual(breaks=c(.05, .25, .5, .75, .95),
                        values=c(1, 1, 1, 1, 1),
                        name="Quantile Factors",
                        labels=c(" 5th  Percentile", "25th Percentile","Median", "75th Percentile", "95th Percentile")) +
                     scale_linetype_manual(breaks=c(.05, .25, .5, .75, .95),
                        values=c("dotted", "dashed","solid", "dashed", "dotted"), 
                        name="Quantile Factors",
                        labels=c(" 5th  Percentile", "25th Percentile","Median", "75th Percentile", "95th Percentile")) 
gg_taus <- gg_taus + theme(legend.title = element_text(size = 10),
                           legend.key=element_rect(size=5), legend.text=element_text(aes(color=fill)))
gg_taus
```

```
Trying to visualize a specific Assessment Areas observations overlaying the first plots quantile lines for a new data set.
```

```
Munger <- ESB_Rebind %>% group_by(SampleID, Assessment_Area) %>% filter(Assessment_Area == "Munger Landing")
glimpse(Munger)
SSA <- paste("SSA #", Munger$Assess_ID [1]) #Creates a label for legend for Assessment ID number
```

```
gg1 <- ggplot(Munger, aes(x=WaterDepth_m,y=S_TMI)) + geom_point(aes(shape=Assessment_Area))+
        theme(panel.border = element_rect(linetype = "solid", fill = NA),panel.grid.major = element_blank(),
        panel.grid.minor = element_blank(),panel.background = element_blank()) + 
        scale_y_continuous(limits = c(0, 1))+
        scale_x_continuous(breaks = seq(from = 0, to = 3, by = 0.5))+
        xlab("Water Depth (meters)") + ylab("Std.Macroinvertebrete Trimetric Index (sTMI)")+
        labs(shape=SSA)
gg1

gg_Munger <- gg1 + 
  geom_quantile(quantiles = taus, aes(linetype = factor(..quantile..),colour = factor(..quantile..), size = factor(..quantile..)))

gg_Munger <- gg_Munger + scale_colour_manual(breaks=c(.05, .25, .5, .75, .95),
                              values=c("red", "red","black", "green", "green"),
                              name="Quantile Factors",
                              labels=c(" 5th  Percentile", "25th Percentile","Median", "75th Percentile", "95th Percentile")) +
                         scale_size_manual(breaks=c(.05, .25, .5, .75, .95),
                              values=c(1, 1, 1, 1, 1),
                              name="Quantile Factors",
                              labels=c(" 5th  Percentile", "25th Percentile","Median", "75th Percentile", "95th Percentile")) +
                         scale_linetype_manual(breaks=c(.05, .25, .5, .75, .95),
                              values=c("dotted", "dashed","solid", "dashed", "dotted"), 
                              name="Quantile Factors",
                              labels=c(" 5th  Percentile", "25th Percentile","Median", "75th Percentile", "95th Percentile")) 

gg_Munger
```

```
  [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/P1dnf.png
  [2]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ua49B.png
```

Comment: Hi and welcome to stack overflow. Could you focus your question a bit better? Also try to include only the bits of code that relate to the problems you have (for example, making the theme prettier or manually setting nice axis breaks probably isn't the crux of the problem).

Comment: Tried to clean it up @teunbrand

Comment: I solved my second question by simple choosing the dataset:  gg_Munger <- gg1 + 
  geom_quantile(data=ESB_REF, quantiles = taus, aes(linetype = factor(..quantile..),colour = factor(..quantile..), size = factor(..quantile..)))

Comment: First question: How do I select the text in the legend and color a selected variable of my choosing? I would like to color Clough Island and Steelton Bay DarkBlue [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/P1dnf.png